# Compile the same scss file multiple times - laravel mix

Tags: laravel, webpack, sass, laravel-mix

I need to compile the same scss file two times, with different sassOptions. Something like:

```
mix.sass('resources/sass/master.scss', 'public/css', {
    sassOptions: {
        includePaths: [
            'resources/sass/firstconfig'
        ],
    }
})
.sass('resources/sass/master.scss', 'public/css', {
    sassOptions: {
        includePaths: [
            'resources/sass/secondconfig'
        ],
    }
})
```

Ideally, this would generate a master_firstconfig.css and a master_secondconfig.css. Then, depending on the current config, I will load the sheet I need (I got this part covered).

Is this possible? When I try to do it, it says I cant mention the same file twice.

Comment: Why not create a master_secondconfig.scss with just @import "master.scss" and then compile it with mix rather than using the same file twice

Comment: Shouldn't that logic be made in the processor? I guess that would solve it, if there is no better approach, I guess I'm going down that path. Thanks.